# Fourier transforms in Real line

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, fourier-restriction

If a function $f \in L^{p}([a,b])$ then is it possible that it's Fourier transform $\widehat{f} \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$. How can we show this?

Comment: Did you mean to say $L^2 ([a,b])$?

Comment: f \in L^{p}([a,b])

Comment: If you are asking for an example then $e^{-x^{2}}$ is in every $L^{p}$ so is its Fourier transform.

Comment: Thank u @Kavi Rama Murthy sir